# complex expression to the power of a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have a math exam tomorrow, and i am not sure with my solution for a exercise. can you please tell me if i am right.
Question is:
$$(1+i)^{(1-i)}$$
My solution is:
$$\sqrt{2} e^{(i {\pi\over4})^{(1-i)}} = \sqrt{2} e^{i {\pi\over4} - i² {\pi\over4}} = \sqrt{2}e^{i{\pi\over2}}$$
Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
changed \pi\over2 to \pi\over4 due to comments, thank you :)

Comment: $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Comment: The argument should be $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ .  Also, I believe the answer is not unique.

Comment: ok thanks, thats a mistkae for shure, but i is it correct when i do it like: $$\sqrt{2} e^{(i {\pi\over4})^{(1-i)}} = \sqrt{2} e^{i {\pi\over4} - i² {\pi\over4}} = \sqrt{2}e^{i{\pi\over2}}$$

Comment: $(1+i)^{(1-i)}=\exp\left(\left(\frac12\ln(2)+i\frac\pi4\right)\cdot(1-i)\right)$

Comment: ok, can you explain please.

Comment: First we write the base term as power-expression:$$1+i = \sqrt{2}\cdot\exp\left(i\frac\pi4\right)=\exp\left(\frac12\ln(2)\right)\cdot\exp\left(i\frac\pi4\right)=\exp\left(\frac12\ln(2)+i\frac\pi4\right)$$ Then we take this to the power of $(1-i)$: $$(1+i)^{(1-i)}=\left(\exp\left(\frac12\ln(2)+i\frac\pi4\right)\right)^{(1-i)}=\exp\left(\left(\frac12\ln(2)+i\frac\pi4\right)\cdot(1-i)\right)$$

Comment: Thats it! Thank You very much, if you want to post it as answer i'll accept it! I'm too new to vote for comments, sry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the comments, because otherwise you shoud elevate $\sqrt{2}$ to the power $(1 - i)$ too.

$ \left( \sqrt{2} e^{(i \frac{\pi}{4})} \right)^{(1-i)} = (\sqrt{2})^{(1-i)} e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}(1-i)}$

Comment: Not yet quite right... Look at my comment...

Comment: Yes you suggested the correct way, I misunderstood the power elevation.

Comment: yeah, i read the comments, tobias showed me my prefered solution :), thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions when raising a number to complex power. For example:
\begin{equation}
i^i=(e^{(2n+1)\pi i})^i=e^{-(2n+1)\pi}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is any integer.

$1-i$ can be also written as $\sqrt2e^{-\pi i/4}$, because
\begin{equation}
\sqrt2e^{-\pi i/4} =\sqrt2\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
=\sqrt2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)=1-i.
\end{equation}
Actually, it's also any of $e^{(2n-1/4)\pi i}$, where $n$ is any integer, because $e^{2n\pi i}=1$.

Therefore, 
\begin{eqnarray}
(1-i)^{1-i}&=&(1-i)(1-i)^{-i} \\
&=& (1-i)(\sqrt2e^{(2n-1/4)\pi i})^{-i} \\
&=& (1-i)e^{-(2n-1/4)\pi} 2^{-i/2} \\
&=& (1-i)e^{-(2n-1/4)\pi} e^{-i(\ln2)/2} \\
&=& (1-i)e^{-(2n-1/4)\pi} \left( \cos\frac{\ln2}{2}-i\sin\frac{\ln2}{2} \right)\\
&=& (1-i)e^{-(2n-1/4)\pi} \left( \cos\frac{\ln2}{2}+\sin\frac{\ln2}{2} \right)\\
\end{eqnarray}